# Create a growing and shrinking SVG canvas in a Qooxdoo window with automatic scrollbars when necessary

Tags: html, svg, qooxdoo

Using Qooxdoo I want to have a window that only contains a HTML SVG element.
This SVG shall use the full available size in the resizable window. And when the window gets too small automatically scrollbars shall appear so that the SVG content is still completely visible (when the user scrolls accordingly)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The some key moments of my solution are:

- Use `qx.ui.embed.Html` as wrapper of svg markup
- Use `qx.ui.container.Scroll` to make a container or widget scrollable
- Use properties `minWidth` and `minHeight` of widget to stop reducing its size
- A root svg element in markup has scallable width and height (in this case 100%)
- Turn off shrinking of svg container (qx.ui.embed.Html) via properties `allowShrinkX: false` and `allowShrinkY: false`

The following code contains all above mentioned things:

```
const win = new qx.ui.window.Window();
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Grow());

const svg = '<svg width="100%" height="100%"><circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" /></svg>';
const svgWidget = new qx.ui.embed.Html(svg);
svgWidget.set({allowShrinkX: false, allowShrinkY: false, minWidth: 200, minHeight: 200});

const scroller = new qx.ui.container.Scroll().set({width: 300, height: 300, decorator: "main", padding: 5});
scroller.add(svgWidget, {width: "100%", height: "100%"});
win.add(scroller);

win.open();

const doc = this.getRoot();
doc.add(win,
{
  left : 100,
  top  : 50
});
```